Build failed with spring tool suite 4.16.1
I am new to Spring Tool Suite and I am trying to build version 4.16.1 of sts4 on LoongArch[1], but I encountered an error. I am using the build command local-build.sh. Is there any problem with what I am doing? I want to adapt sts4 to LoongArch. Do I need to do any additional work?
Thanks
[ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load p2 repository with ID 'p2-thirdparty-bundles' from location https://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/third-party/misc-p2-repo/3.9.4.201902271843: No repository found at https://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/third-party/misc-p2-repo/3.9.4.201902271843. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load p2 repository with ID 'p2-thirdparty-bundles' from location https://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/third-party/misc-p2-repo/3.9.4.201902271843
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:47)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:72)

[1] https://www.loongson.cn/EN/application/list?id=39
Building sts4 on LoongArch

All the repositories under https://dist.springsource.com moved to a new location: https://cdn.spring.io/spring-tools/, so you need to change those repository locations in the pom.xml files.
In addition to that the local-build.sh file is slightly outdated if you checked out the repo from that 4.16.1.RELEASE tag, so you need to switch the profile over to the one of the underlying Eclipse platform that you would like to run the build against, e.g. -Pe425 to build for Eclipse 2022-09.

If you run into additional issues, I would recommend to open an issue at https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/ to get further help with this.

After reading your answer, I've decided to upgrade the version to 4.21.1.RELEASE and try again.
